# Why is getCell() returning "Range" instead of the values?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I am working on a very simple script, that logs the values in a column, I've used a similar structure in Google Apps Script before with great success, but I can't see the problem here. The "statusColumn" is filled with different values, and when I try to log them like this, it returns "Range" for all the rows. Any suggestions on why this is?

```
var statusColumn = 1;

function getOrders() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("12y85GmJ94s6k3213j2nGK8rFr0GOfd_Emfk8WHu_MUQ");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
    var orders  = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows  = orders.getNumRows();

    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        var status = orders.getCell(i, statusColumn);
        Logger.log([status]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
var statusColumn = 1;

function getOrders() {

     var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("12y85GmJ94s6k3213j2nGK8rFr0GOfd_Emfk8WHu_MUQ");
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
     var orders  = sheet.getDataRange();
     var numRows  = orders.getNumRows();

     for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
         var statusCell = orders.getCell(i, statusColumn).getValue();
         Logger.log(statusCell)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCell()` returns a Range object, in this case the range represents a single cell, but the Range object may also represent a group of cells. You are looking for the Value of the cell, which can be retrieved from the Range by using getValue().

```
Logger.log(status.getValue());
```

See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()

By the way, the approach you are using (fetching one cell at a time) is very inefficient. Instead you should fetch the entire column with getRange(), then get all the values with getValues(). GetValues() will return an Array, with all of your status values.

These functions are all documented at the links above.

Comment: How would I then specify the values within the for loop, when using .getValues(), like if I wanted to specify that now I am handling the statusCell, which is in column 1, (The statusColumn). Because it would be different as I would no longer have to get the value again?

Comment: Never mind, I found out how to reference it, posted in anwer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the function that does exactly what it's name says; gets you the **range**.

To get the value of a range you need to use `.getValues()`.

Example code:

```
sheet.getRange('A1:A3').getValues();
```

The only difference between `.getRange()` and `.getDataRange()` is that the former will select only the range you specify, which is good if you want to limit the range to something specific in your sheet, while the later vill automatically find alll values in the sheet and return back you.

Any empty cells will look like `[notemptycell, , ,]` and that's an array were you have 3 empty cells on that row.

Remember; the object you have returned to you is an array of arrays and thus you need to for loop twice a la this patter:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // Loops through the rows
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    // Loops through the columns of a row
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello I posted a change under edit, where I tried doing what @Cameron Roberts' answer below, and this works, I also tried using the .getValues, but to no luck, I can't seem to reference each individual cell. I guess I would have to create some kind of variable, like var statusCell = order(i, statusColumn) or something? (I know the example won't work, it's just to show my point :))

Comment: It looks like you figured out how to use it into your own code and that's great. There's no difference in the separation you did and `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`. You'll have an array of arrays returned to you as a value and that's why your original for loop didn't work.

Comment: Yes I understand now, it's very smart, and ofCourse much faster now that I am testing it out :) But I have a different problem, I used one of the Google Tutorals on appscript, the one with emails, to avoid repeating sending emails, as far as I can tell I've done everything the same way, but it seems to ignore by "SENT" marking. I posted it under EDIT.

Comment: Try `Logger.log(typeof system)` and see what it prints you.

Comment: It logs: string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string? :D

Comment: There you have it; system is an array of strings, and it's not the cell you think it is.

Comment: But it is what has been done here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails?hl=en isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93841/discussion-between-william-larsen-bang-and-gemtastic).